# hibernate using one to many returns

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate , so sorry if the question might be stupid but I tried searching for the answer and could not find a solution.

I have 2 tables "question" and "possibleAnswers",
the relationship is oneToMany (meaning each question have few possible answers) 
the DB has FK between the 2 tables and I run hibernate configuration to create the hibernate files automatically, when I am fetching the data I am getting cross join meanig if i have 3 questions and 4 answers (1 Q has 2 possbile answers ) but instead of getting 4 records i am getting 12 records
i don't know if my maping is wrong or the HQL i am using.

Here are all the relevant files

This is what I see in the log

```
select
    questions0_.question_id as question1_4_0_,
    possiblean1_.possible_answer_id as possible1_3_1_,
    questions0_.answer_type as answer_t2_4_0_,
    questions0_.display_order as display_3_4_0_,
    questions0_.question_text as question4_4_0_,
    possiblean1_.answer_value as answer_v2_3_1_,
    possiblean1_.question_id as question3_3_1_ 
from
    edi_ms.questions questions0_ cross 
join
    edi_ms.possible_answers possiblean1_
```

this is the java code I am running 
getQuestions.java:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session =   sessionFactory.openSession();
Query<Questions> query = session.createQuery("from Questions, PossibleAnswers");
List<Questions> questions = (List<Questions>)query.list();
return questions
```

Questions.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions", schema = "edi_ms")
public class Questions implements java.io.Serializable {

private long questionId;

private String questionText;
private String answerType;
private Long displayOrder;
private Set<PossibleAnswers> possibleAnswerses = new HashSet<PossibleAnswers>(0);
public Questions() {
}

public Questions(long questionId, 
                String questionText) {
    this.questionId = questionId;
    this.questionText = questionText;
}

public Questions(long questionId, 
        String questionText, String answerType, Long displayOrder,
        Set<PossibleAnswers> possibleAnswerses, Set<MembersAnswers> membersAnswerses) {
    this.questionId = questionId;
    this.questionText = questionText;
    this.answerType = answerType;
    this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
    this.possibleAnswerses = possibleAnswerses;
}

@Id

@Column(name = "question_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public long getQuestionId() {
    return this.questionId;
}

public void setQuestionId(long questionId) {
    this.questionId = questionId;
}

@Column(name = "question_text", nullable = false)
public String getQuestionText() {
    return this.questionText;
}

public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
    this.questionText = questionText;
}

@Column(name = "answer_type", length = 1)
public String getAnswerType() {
    return this.answerType;
}

public void setAnswerType(String answerType) {
    this.answerType = answerType;
}

@Column(name = "display_order")
public Long getDisplayOrder() {
    return this.displayOrder;
}

public void setDisplayOrder(Long displayOrder) {
    this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "questions")
@JsonbTransient
public Set<PossibleAnswers> getPossibleAnswerses() {
    return this.possibleAnswerses;
}

@JsonbTransient
public void setPossibleAnswerses(Set<PossibleAnswers> possibleAnswerses) {
    this.possibleAnswerses = possibleAnswerses;
}
}
```

Questions.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="true" default-access="property" default- 
cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
<class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" name="HibernateDBFiles.Questions" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" schema="edi_ms" select-before-update="false" table="questions">
    <id name="questionId" type="long">
        <column name="question_id"/>
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>

    <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="questionText" optimistic-lock="true" type="string" unique="false">
        <column name="question_text" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="answerType" optimistic-lock="true" type="string" unique="false">
        <column length="1" name="answer_type"/>
    </property>
    <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="displayOrder" optimistic-lock="true" type="java.lang.Long" unique="false">
        <column name="display_order"/>
    </property>
    <set embed-xml="true" fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" mutable="true" name="possibleAnswerses" optimistic-lock="true" sort="unsorted" table="possible_answers">
        <key on-delete="noaction">
            <column name="question_id" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="HibernateDBFiles.PossibleAnswers" embed-xml="true" not-found="exception"/>
    </set> 

</class>
```

PossibleAnswers.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "possible_answers", schema = "edi_ms")
public class PossibleAnswers implements java.io.Serializable {

private long possibleAnswerId;
private Questions questions;
private String answerValue;


public PossibleAnswers() {
}

public PossibleAnswers(long possibleAnswerId, Questions questions, String answerValue) {
    this.possibleAnswerId = possibleAnswerId;
    this.questions = questions;
    this.answerValue = answerValue;
}



@Id

@Column(name = "possible_answer_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public long getPossibleAnswerId() {
    return this.possibleAnswerId;
}

public void setPossibleAnswerId(long possibleAnswerId) {
    this.possibleAnswerId = possibleAnswerId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = false)
@JsonbTransient
public Questions getQuestions() {
    return this.questions;
}
@JsonbTransient
public void setQuestions(Questions questions) {
    this.questions = questions;
}

@Column(name = "answer_value", nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getAnswerValue() {
    return this.answerValue;
}

public void setAnswerValue(String answerValue) {
    this.answerValue = answerValue;
}


}
```

PossbleAnswers.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="true" default-access="property" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
<class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" name="HibernateDBFiles.PossibleAnswers" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" schema="edi_ms" select-before-update="false" table="possible_answers">
    <id name="possibleAnswerId" type="long">
        <column name="possible_answer_id"/>
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one class="HibernateDBFiles.Questions" embed-xml="true" fetch="select" insert="true" name="questions" not-found="exception" optimistic-lock="true" unique="false" update="true">
        <column name="question_id" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one> 
    <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="answerValue" optimistic-lock="true" type="string" unique="false">
        <column length="50" name="answer_value" not-null="true"/>
    </property>

</class>
```

Comment: First, xml files are completely useless and obsolete: annotations already define the mapping. Second: just query for questions: `select q from Question q`. Questions will be returned, and Questions have answers, so you'll be able to access them if needed. Note that the entity should be named `Question`, not `Questions`: an instance of that class is ONE question. The class String is named String, not STrings, because an instance of STring is one string.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried just    Query<Questions> query = session.createQuery("from Questions"); and i got only 3 answers (onlu questions table )

Comment: Well, of course, since there **are** only 3 questions in the table. Why would you get anything else? Iterate through these questions, call getPossibleAnswerses (again, the naming!), and iterate through the returned set, and you'll have the answers of the question.

Comment: thank you for your help but 
this does not make since ,
i expect hibernate to get the records according to the one to many 
if hibernate is not getting the records from possibleAnswers table then what is the idea of using oneToMany ? 
by the way i also tried to delete the xbm files and i got en error that xbm file does not exists

Comment: Hibernate will load the answers when you'll first access them from the questions. That's the whole idea of an ORM. You load a question, and you can navigate through the graph: get the answers of the qestions, get the author of the answers, get the city of the author, get the country of the city, etc. etc. and Hibernate loads the data from the database as needed. And if you modify anything, it will be saved for you.

Comment: You need to use `distinct` questions when you select with a join otherwise you will get a question for each answer.

Comment: After you used `Query<Questions> query = session.createQuery("from Questions");` how did you retrieve the possible answers?

`query.list()` returns a List of `Questions` (`List<Questions>`), each question can be traversed to get its `PossibleAnswers`.

At index 0 of the List (`Questions question = questions.get(0);`) you have a persistent instance of the first question, and calling `question.getPossibleAnswerses();` will give you two `PossibleAnswers`.

Continuing with the approach if you call the other indexes of your list (index 1 and 2) you will get 1 `PossibleAnswers` at index 1...

Comment: ... and another `PossibleAnswers` at index 2. In total you should get all 4 `PossibleAnswers` and not 12.

I suspect you are getting 12 `PossibleAnswers` because in your HQL you are selecting `from Questions, PossibleAnswers`. Try selecting `from Questions` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.. 
I found the problems , the original query is now working and there is no need to loop over the response

```
Query<Questions> query = session.createQuery("from Questions ");
```

the problem was that since I am working with JSON I added

```
@JsonbTransient
```

in the PossibleAnswers.java like this

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = false)
@JsonbTransient
public Questions getQuestions() {
    return this.questions;
}
@JsonbTransient
public void setQuestions(Questions questions) {
    this.questions = questions;
}
```

from what I understand this is done to prevent endless loop (before i added it , this is what happenned ) 
the problem was that I added this also to the Questions.java 
once I removed it , it works !!
(if some has more info on the @JsonbTransient I would love to learn )

Answer (score 0):

Here your query is wrong update query is

```
   SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session =   sessionFactory.openSession();
Query<Questions> query = session.createQuery("from Questions");
List<Questions> questions = (List<Questions>)query.list();
return questions
```